# How do you set up multiple JDBC database pools in Adobe/Day CQ5?

Tags: jdbc, adobe, connection-pooling, aem, day-cq

Using Adobe (Day) Communique 5, I've been using the standard JDBC Connections Pool service for my first database, and it works well. Now I need to configure more connection pools for other databases.

When I go to /system/console, Configurations, JDBC Connections Pool, I only see one configurable JDBC connection. Is there a way to set up multiple ones?

Comment: Hi, which database have you connected to CQ5 using JDBC Connections Pool service . I am trying to connect MySQL database in my website in place of JCR . Can you suggest or give the steps for doing the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which version of CQ5?
In CQ5.4 and CQ5.3, you can configure multiple JDBC Connection Pools. Notice the "+" sign.

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_cq.html#OSGi%20Configuration